# Javascript childArray.filter() nested within parentArray.map() isn't filtering

Tags: javascript

I would like to return an updated array to state, so I am using map with filter as follows:

```
state.assignmentClusters.map(cluster => {
                cluster.files.forEach(file => {
                    file.motifList.filter(motif =>{
                        return motif.motif_id !== state.motifIdToDelete;
                    });
                });
            });
```

Since I need to return an array, I am using `map()` on first array, the 2nd one (file) i'm just going over it without expecting to mutate anything, so I used `forEach()` and in the last depth, I am using `filter()` to return all motifs **except** for those that their id is equal to `state.motifIdToDelete`  (just fyi, both IDs are strings).

PS, this piece of code is within a Vue mutation function that allows me to mutate state (like reducer in react).

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks,
bud.

Comment: please add some data and the wanted result. btw, your filter filters in the void, as some others not retuning any usefull.

Comment: you need to return from map

Comment: what's the point of the filter inside the forEach

Comment: Please add the before & after of the data you are iterating on.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this differently yet I would like to grant the answer to the person who can show me how to preform this correctly with `filter()`

this currently works:

```
state.assignmentClusters.forEach(cluster => {
                    cluster.files.forEach(file => {
                        file.motifList.forEach((motif, index) =>{
                            if (motif.motif_id == state.motifIdToDelete) {
                                file.motifList.splice(index, 1)
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
```

Answer (score -1):

Your call to `state.assignmentClusters.map` returns nothing. You should return `cluster` in the arrow function.
Also, your call to `file.motifList.filter` doesn't mutate anything. You must use the value returned by the `filter` function somewhere.

```
state.assignmentClusters.map(cluster => {
    cluster.files = cluster.files.map(file => {
        file.motifList = file.motifList.filter(motif => {
            return motif.motif_id !== state.motifIdToDelete;
        });
        return file;
    });
    return cluster;
});
```

Another option if mutation doesn't matter:

```
state.assignmentClusters.forEach(cluster => {
    cluster.files.forEach(file => {
        file.motifList = file.motifList.filter(motif => {
            return motif.motif_id !== state.motifIdToDelete;
        });
    });
});
```